# Class use in different element (other jQuery selector not working)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone explain to me or point me to other solution for this:

`class fruit` is in two different tag element, and one element has `add class` use in jquery selector, but the alertbox is not showing. `("add is clicked")`

```
 <table>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="#" class="add fruit">Apple</a></td>
            <td><a href="#" class="fruit">Apple 2</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="#" class="add fruit">Banana</a></td>
            <td><a href="#" class="fruit">Banana 2</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Also when i clicked the `Apple` link, i want the two alert box to show.
see this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/x957pbrr/) for demo.

```
$('.add').off("click").on("click", function () {
    alert("add is clicked");
});

$('.fruit').off("click").on("click", function () {
    alert("fruit is clicked");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are already doing it correct, just remove "off".

```
    $('.fruit').on("click", function () {
     alert("fruit is clicked");

   });
  $('.add').on("click", function () {
     alert("add is clicked");
  });
```

Comment: Yes, its working, but i forget why i used off, but before i have problem when not using with the `.off'

Comment: Probably you were missing some important part due to which the code was not working then. "Off" unbinds all the previous events, so you should use "off" in very specific requirements. :) Happy coding

Comment: Ok sir,i found the problem now. when i only use the 'on'.somewhat my links are hang(i do load jsp file to a certain div on a page). and using `off' prevent that issue

Answer (score 0):

Don't really know what you did, but i think you would like to have this results.

```
$('.add').click(function () {
    alert("add is clicked");
});
$('.fruit').click(function () {
    alert("fruit is clicked");
});
```

Look here :

http://jsfiddle.net/x957pbrr/1/

Comment: thanks.but only alertbox for fruit is showing,even i click the `Apple` which should be show alertbox for 'add is clicked'

Answer (score 0):

In your Fiddle, you are using `off("click")` before the `on("click", function...)`.  The first off clears all previously registered click handlers.  So you are turning off the `add` click handler before you add the `fruit` click handler

Answer (score 0):

The `off` [method](http://api.jquery.com/off/) unbinds all prior bound click events.
I think you would be better off putting these events into one handler.

```
$('.fruit').click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('add'))
        alert("add is clicked");
    else
        alert("fruit is clicked");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use ".off('click')" in 2, you remove the event handler added in 1.

```
1. ---

$('.add').off("click").on("click", function () {
 alert("add is clicked");
});

2. ---

$('.fruit').off("click").on("click", function () {
 alert("fruit is clicked");
});
```

Put it in reverse order:

```
$('.fruit').off("click").on("click", function () {
 alert("fruit is clicked");
});

$('.add').off("click").on("click", function () {
 alert("add is clicked");
});
```

Read this: http://api.jquery.com/off/

Comment: Thanks.but when i click add, it should also show `fruit uis clicked`